# How to get rid of leading zero before the decimal point in a double less than one?

Tags: java, floating-point

I am doing a rather large project (for me, is an AP JAVA course in high school).  Anyways, for a portion of the project I need to be able to round a decimal and output it without the zero at the beginning before the decimal.

Ex: .4999 rounds ---> 0.5
I need: .4999 round ---> .5

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must learn to distinguish a) a value of some type like double b) the human readable String describing this value. - Rounding is a mathematical operation and doesn't concern itself with "decimals"

Comment: Yes, I understand this, I was just less clear and didn't explain every step.  I round it is as a double then use Double.toString(a) to manipulate the string.

Answer (score 3):

As Ingo mentioned, you'll need to get a String representation of the number in order to modify the output as desired. One solution would be to use [java.text.NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). `setMinimumIntegerDigits(0)` seems to fit the bill. I'm sure there are plenty more options as well.

Comment: 1+, I was not aware of `setMinimumIntegerDigits`. I've updated my working example to include [your answer](http://ideone.com/BhiplP). It is nice to know that there is a standard way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static String format(double value, int decimalPlaces) {
   if (value >= 1 || value < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be between 0 and 1");
   }
   final String tmp = String.format("%." + decimalPlaces + "f", value);
   return tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf('.'));
}
```

Examples:

```
System.out.println(format(0.4999d, 1)); // .5
System.out.println(format(0.0299d, 2)); // .03
System.out.println(format(0.34943d, 3)); // .349
```

[Working Fiddle](http://ideone.com/BhiplP)

Comment: No problem, you can also replace `tmp.indexOf('.')` for `1`, I've kept it there because my original code was intended to extract decimal places from any positive number. Feel free to accept either mine or @briancherron answer which is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

The [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class can be used.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.0");
System.out.println("Value: " + df.format(value));
```

Comment: DecimalFormat might be useful, but the format presented does not provide the OPs desired output: "I need: .4999 round ---> .5".

Answer (score 0):

May seem weird to you, but you can use `regex` to strip off the leading zero like this:

(assuming that you already know how to round the decimal place to one)

```
        double value = 0.5;

        String val = Double.toString( value ).replaceAll( "^0(\\..*)$", "$1" );

        System.out.println( val );
```

Console:

```
       .5
```