# How do you get rid of the 0 before the decimal point using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently trying to format a calculated value so that it follows the format ".number" with no 0 in front of the decimal point. However, no matter what permutations of tags I've used, none have worked thus far. I know there is an answer to this question in Java: [How to get rid of leading zero before the decimal point in a double less than one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893905/how-to-get-rid-of-leading-zero-before-the-decimal-point-in-a-double-less-than-on), but I have yet to see one for javascript (specifically d3*). If anyone could help, that'd be awesome. Thanks!

*I am using version 4